# How to drag and drop from one coordinate to another C#

Tags: c#, selenium

I have made a number of tests and I'm using Selenium run them. I need to preform a mouse click on a coordinate and hold the mouse down and release it at a different coordinate. I have tried using `action.DragAndDrop()` but I don't want to select a target element. Is there a way I can just say do a mouse down at a certain coordinate and a mouse up on a different coordinate? I would like to do this without having to use Javascript

Answer (score 1):

This is what I am using and works perfectly. You don't need a target element, just the element to move:

```
(new Actions(Driver)).DragAndDropToOffset(element, xoffset, yoffset).Perform();
```

x- and y-offset are simply the int x-y coordinates of where you want the element moved to.

Comment: Worked great for me!